# how to allocate memory to JVM

Tags: jenkins, memory, jvm, tomcat7, artifactory

My instance specifications are,

16 GB RAM, 100 GB Storage, 4 vCPU, centos 7

I have installed jdk 1.8, Jfrog artifactory and jenkins in same instance.

Jfrog artifactory working fine but Jenkins getting killed automatically. i don't know how to debug this issue.

please find screenshot of top,

[image]

setenv.sh

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -server -d64 -XX:NewSize=6g -XX:MaxNewSize=6g -Xms8g -Xmx8g -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:SurvivorRatio=30 -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=12"
```

i have allocated more memory to JVM (-Xms8g -Xmx8g), but both artifactory and jenkins consuming only 3GB memory only (refer from screen shot used memory).

i am assuming because of this only jenkins getting killed automatically.

i invested lot of time to on this, not able to debug it.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Jenkins log,

```
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.93
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 16 2019 17:13:17 UTC
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.93.0
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64/jre
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-7
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-7
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7/conf/logging.properties
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Duser.timezone=GMT
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:NewSize=6g
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:MaxNewSize=6g
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xms8g
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xmx8g
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:PermSize=1024m
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:SurvivorRatio=30
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+UseParNewGC
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:ParallelGCThreads=12
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-7
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-7
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-7/temp
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 6965 ms
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.93
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/ROOT.war
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:16 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig validateSecurityRoles
WARNING: Security role name ** used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jenkins home directory: /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 43,839 ms
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/docs
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/docs has finished in 296 ms
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/examples
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/examples has finished in 1,651 ms
Apr 08, 2019 2:02:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/host-manager
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/host-manager has finished in 565 ms
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/manager
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/manager has finished in 331 ms
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 48810 ms
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:17 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:21 PM hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy createPluginWrapper
WARNING: Deprecated unpacked classes directory found in /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:21 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Apr 08, 2019 2:03:28 PM ruby.RubyRuntimePlugin start
INFO: Injecting JRuby into XStream
Trying to load models from /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/api.rb
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/project.rb:25 warning: already initialized constant MultipleScmsPluginAvailable
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/crumb_exclusion.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/gitlab_notifier.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action.rb
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action.rb:12 warning: already initialized constant WEB_HOOK_ROOT_URL
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action_descriptor.rb
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action_descriptor.rb:10 warning: already initialized constant MERGE_REQUEST_PROCESSING
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action_descriptor.rb:11 warning: already initialized constant MERGED_BRANCH_PROCESSING
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action_descriptor.rb:12 warning: already initialized constant AUTOMATIC_PROJECT_CREATION_PROPERTY
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action_descriptor.rb:13 warning: already initialized constant MASTER_BRANCH_PROPERTY
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action_descriptor.rb:14 warning: already initialized constant USE_MASTER_PROJECT_NAME_PROPERTY
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/root_action_descriptor.rb:15 warning: already initialized constant DESCRIPTION_PROPERTY
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/unprotected_root_action.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/exceptions/bad_request_exception.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/exceptions/configuration_exception.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/exceptions/not_found_exception.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/build_scm.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/flat_keys_hash.rb
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/flat_keys_hash.rb:4 warning: already initialized constant FLATTENED_KEYS_DELIMITER
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/get_build_actions.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/get_build_cause.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/get_jenkins_projects.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/get_parameters_values.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/parse_request.rb
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/parse_request.rb:11 warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_BODY
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/services/security.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/use_cases/build_now.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/use_cases/create_project_for_branch.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/use_cases/notify_commit.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/use_cases/process_commit.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/use_cases/process_delete_commit.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/use_cases/process_merge_request.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/util/settings.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/abstract_details.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/commit.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/merge_request_details.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/parameters_request_details.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/payload_request_details.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/project.rb
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/project.rb:21 warning: already initialized constant MultipleScmsPluginAvailable
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/project.rb:25 warning: already initialized constant MultipleScmsPluginAvailable
/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/project.rb:30 warning: already initialized constant BRANCH_NAME_PARAMETER_ACCEPTED_TYPES
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/repository_uri.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/request_details.rb
Loading /home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/gitlab-hook/WEB-INF/classes/models/values/scm_data.rb
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:10 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:10 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:12 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error
INFO: Failed to instantiate optional component hudson.plugins.build_timeout.operations.AbortAndRestartOperation$DescriptorImpl; skipping
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:13 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.AnonymousClassWarnings warn
WARNING: Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles$1 in file:/home/jenkins-ci/.jenkins/plugins/config-file-provider/WEB-INF/lib/config-file-provider.jar; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:14 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:14 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins setBuildsAndWorkspacesDir
INFO: Using non default workspaces directories: ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}.
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:15 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:16 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:16 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 156 ms
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:16 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@4c0b0e38: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon Apr 08 14:05:16 GMT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:16 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@4c0b0e38]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@22e1b981
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:16 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@22e1b981: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@13b0965a: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon Apr 08 14:05:17 GMT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@13b0965a]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7eed5ae0
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:17 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7eed5ae0: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:17 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Apr 08, 2019 2:05:17 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please show us the content of jenkins log file

Comment: Jenkins log is clear. i didn't find any error.

Comment: @dieter i added jenkins log

Comment: So there are no shut down logs or error logs? that would mean some one kills ungracefully your jenkins instance.

Comment: @dieter yes, i checked system log (message). there also i didn't get any message. i did dmesg. there also no killed message

Comment: I won't set the minimum heap size unless you are very sure you want to allocate that much space. Are you sure you want Jenkins to use so much memory? The default would be 4 GB of heap maximum, I would try not setting the heap size at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended heap size for Jenkins is a minimum of 200MB. I would try not setting the heap size and see if this works. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/hardware-recommendations/

When you force to have a minimum of 8 GB heap (plus the rest of the memory the JVM uses) you risk the process being killed for using too much resources.

NOTE: Java 8+ doesn't have a Perm Gen so there is no point trying to set it. Most likely you can just remove those options too.